# How to visualize system log data in "phase space"?

Tags: data-visualization, matlab, outliers

First I have to tell my experience in development is extremely thin (a few bash scripts that's all) so bear with me if I can't keep up :)

A little background story to begin:

A few years ago during my sysadmin formation I had the chance to meet a senior security expert which showed me something I found wonderful, phase space visualization of system logs with [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). (By "system logs" I mean logs from routers/switches/firewalls/webservers/database servers/etc...)

That person used this type of visualization to detect anomalies in behavior of computer systems by mapping them "in phases [sic] space" (I don't know if I can employ the term this way.)
The result had generally the aspect of a sphere (when represented in 3D) but protruding from it were "significant events" (anomalies in this case).
The same person showed my once how he could map this differently and it had the aspect of Lorenz attractors ([This page has images which are very similar to what he showed me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aLorenz_caos2.png))

The resulting visualization may seem to have no meanginful output given that I would plot IP addresses against time against URLs for example, remember my goal is only to detect unusual behaviors, those who depart from the general ones.

**The question:** The problem I have is I lost the "formula" to plot system logs "in phases space" could you help me to find it ?
I'm not directly interested in working code, the formula in pseudocode to plot those logs would already make me happy :)

Given my weak skills in math and development I'm not sure I explained clearly my point so here are some resources I found related to this subject:

- [here is an example webserver access log, that's the type of logs i want to plot](http://notebook.cowgar.com/access.log)
- [a whitepaper](http://rp-www.cs.usyd.edu.au/~comp5318/survey/anomaly.pdf) describing anomaly detection, it seems pretty similar to what I want to do
- the abstract of [this whitepaper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1981210) seems to fit the idea too but I don't have access to it

PS: an article for math-guys I just stumbled upon, take it like a little present for your kindness to, at least, read my question which I think is a bit blurry due to my lack of skill: https://christopherolah.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/the-real-3d-mandelbrot-set/

Comment: This description sounds like either *spectral anomaly detection* or reduction of dimensions and clustering via [tag:PCA].  Given that your description and question are so vague, could you indicate specifically what kind of plot you are interested in the anomaly detection paper?  (After all, it displays dozens of different plots!)

Comment: The general aspect of the spherical representation which was showed to me resemble to this: http://www.cs.sandia.gov/~smartin/Cyclo_Octane.png with hue and brightness to represent extra dimensions but plotting on orthogonal axis like fig.6(a) in the first whitepaper (anomaly.pdf) and adding colors should be ok for my needs. Thank you for your interest :)

Answer (score 3):

You question is interesting but a bit vague. anyway since you have data try this approach to cluster them using x-means algorithm (matlab or octave) and plot the output. the plot will reveal the subgroups within your data. test each subgroup for system behavior change and grade its effect.

For labeled data use of one example to initialize the clustering exercise then plot the output. this helps you to see which data points are away from the clusters- may be anomalies